# "Cannot read property 'charCodeAt" of undefined"

Tags: jhipster

On the online JDL-studio, I create a JDL file without any errors. After importing it, I get an error "TypeError: cannot read property 'charCodeAt" of undefined". How to find out the cause?

```
Error running generator entities: TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
at module.exports (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/ret/lib/index.js:75:54)
at new RandExp (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/randexp/lib/randexp.js:26:19)
at new RandexpWithFaker (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/utils/faker.js:26:5)
at Faker.faker.createRandexp (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/utils/faker.js:61:41)
at Object.field.createRandexp (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/utils/field.js:360:37)
at generateFakeDataForField (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/utils/field.js:101:29)
at Object.field.generateFakeData (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/utils/field.js:365:16)
at /Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/database-changelog-liquibase/index.js:136:28
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at module.exports.prepareFakeData (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/database-changelog-liquibase/index.js:120:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1024:25)
at /Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/run-async/index.js:49:25
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at /Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/run-async/index.js:26:19
at runLoop.add.once.once (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1025:11)
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/grouped-queue/lib/subqueue.js:48:34)
ERROR! Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charCodeAt' of undefined
at module.exports (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/ret/lib/index.js:75:54)
at new RandExp (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/randexp/lib/randexp.js:26:19)
at new RandexpWithFaker (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/utils/faker.js:26:5)
at Faker.faker.createRandexp (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/utils/faker.js:61:41)
at Object.field.createRandexp (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/utils/field.js:360:37)
at generateFakeDataForField (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/utils/field.js:101:29)
at Object.field.generateFakeData (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/utils/field.js:365:16)
at /Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/database-changelog-liquibase/index.js:136:28
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at module.exports.prepareFakeData (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/database-changelog-liquibase/index.js:120:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1024:25)
at /Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/run-async/index.js:49:25
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at /Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/run-async/index.js:26:19
at runLoop.add.once.once (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:1025:11)
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Documents/workspace/myapp/node_modules/grouped-queue/lib/subqueue.js:48:34)
```

Comment: `charCodeAt()` is used on string
Check if you are passing any undefined variable or the variable is type of string
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt

Comment: @GaëlMarziou The npm is 7.19 and the Node is v14.17.1.

Comment: The cause seems to be in the pattern for email.

Comment: Well JHipster regex have always puzzled me, I never know if I should express as js regex or java regex. In your case, it's the faker that fails, as a workaround you could skip it with `--skip-fake-data` maybe it works also in JDL using `skipFakeData` but the doc does not mention it. Maybe there's an issue in faker.js lib. Life would be simpler if JHipster would support email field type, we could use validator annotation on backend and probably the equivalent in frontend and faker. You probably should report it on github

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks for your insight. I will file a bug report about it along with other issues.

Answer (score 1):

I find that its cause is the following email pattern:

```
email  String required minlength(6) maxlength(255) pattern(/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/) unique,
```

Now, a question would be what is the acceptable email pattern for JHipster.